# URL general format

Tags: c++, url, format

I have written a C++ program that allows URLs to be posted onto YouTube. It works by taking in the URL as input either from you typing it into the program or from direct input, and then it will replace every '/', '.' in the string with '*'. This modified string is then put on your clipboard (this is solely for Windows-users).

Of course, before I can even call the program usable, it has to go back: I will need to know when '.', '/' are used in URLs. I have looked at this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator , and know that '.' is used when dealing with the "master website" (in the case of this URL, "en.wikipedia.org"), and then '/' is used afterwards, but I have been to other websites, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , where this simply isn't the case (it even replaced '(', ')' with "%28", "%29", respectively!)

I also seemed to have requested a .aspx file, whatever that is. Also, there is a '.' inside the parentheses in that URL. I have even tried to view the regular expressions (I don't quite fully understand those yet...) regarding URLs. Could someone tell me (or link me to) the rules regarding the use of '.', '/' in URLs?

Comment: Under "References" at the bottom of the Wikipedia article you linked, are further links to the relevant specifications.  There is no quick and helpful answer here; you need to spend some time reading them before progressing.

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain why you are doing this convoluted thing? What are you trying to achieve? It may be that you don't need to know as much as you think, once you answer that question.

In the mean time here is some information. A URL is really comprised of a number of sections

```
http:     - the "scheme" or protocol used to access the resource. "HTTP", "HTTPS",
            "FTP", etc are all examples of a scheme. There are many others

//        - separates the protocol from the host (server) address

myserver.org - the host. The host name is looked up against a DNS (Dynamic Name Server)
            service and resolved to an IP address - the "phone number" of the machine
            which can serve up the resource (like "98.139.183.24" for www.yahoo.com)

www.myserver.org - the host with a prefix. Sometimes the same domain (`myserver.org`)
            connects multiple servers (or ports) and you can be sent straight to the
            right server with the prefix (mail., www., ftp., ... up to the
            administrators of the domain). Conventionally, a server that serves content
            intended for viewing with a browser has a `www.` prefix, but there's no rule
            that says this must be the case. 

:8080/    - sometimes, you see a colon followed by up to five digits after the domain.
            this indicates the PORT on the server where you are accessing data
            some servers allow certain specific services on just a particular port
            they might have a "public access" website on port 80, and another one on 8080
            the https:// protocol defaults to port 443, there are ports for telnet, ftp, 
            etc. Add these things only if you REALLY know what you are doing.

/the/pa.th/ this is the path relative to DOCUMENTROOT on the server where the
            resource is located. `.` characters are legal here, just as they are in
            directory structures. 

file.html
file.php
file.asp
etc       - usually the resource being fetched is a file. The file may have
            any of a great number of extensions; some of these indicate to the server that
            instead of sending the file straight to the requester,
            it has to execute a program or other instructions in this file,
            and send the result of that
            Examples of extensions that indicate "active" pages include
            (this is not nearly exhaustive - just "for instance"):
            .php = contains a php program
            .py  = contains a python program
            .js  = contains a javascript program
                   (usually called from inside an .htm or .html)
            .asp = "active server page" associated with a
                   Microsoft Internet Information Server
```

?something=value&somethingElse=%23othervalue%23 
               parameters that are passed to the server can be shown in the URL.
               This can be used to pass parameters, entries in a form, etc.
               Any character might be passed here - including '.', '&', '/', ...
               But you can't just write those characters in your string...

Now comes the fun part.

URLs cannot contain certain characters (quite a few, actually). In order to get around this, there exists a mechanism called "escaping" a character. Typically this means replacing a character with the hexadecimal equivalent, prefixed with a `%` sign. Thus, you frequently see a space character represented as %20, for example. You can find a handly list [here](http://web.forret.com/tools/charmap.asp?show=ascii)

There are many functions available for converting "illegal" characters in a URL automatically to a "legal" value.

To learn about exactly what is and isn't allowed, you really need to go back to the original specifications.  See for example

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

I list them in chronological order - the last one being the most recent.

But I repeat my question -- what are you really trying to do here, and why?

Comment: I am trying to make it so that you can post a link on YouTube (or some forum where websites are not allowed). I am doing this because there have been times where the people viewing a certain page might benefit by knowing something someone else viewing the page has found out. For example, I was watching a video on YouTube about a (potentially evil) man named Lloyd Irvin. He is alleged of running a "cult" inside his chain of martial arts schools, and I had some information regarding that "person". I couldn't post it because of YouTube's ridiculously strict URL-ban.

Comment: Good God, I know now just how complex a URL-decrypter/encrypter will be! The easy part was the "encrypting" of a valid URL...the hard part is going to be to check that, not only is the link valid, but that it conforms to all the stuff you sent me, not to mention the fact that the URL corresponding to a Google search looks WAY different (as far as '.', '/' is concerned) than other websites... //sounds like a trial-and-error process

Comment: Google is your friend. Find a phrase on your target site ("phrase" can span multiple sentences) that looks reasonably unique, copy it into your search box, surround it by quotes and confirm you get one hit - the page you want to link to. Tell people to 'google "the unique phrase on this website"' - you have just created an "encoded unique resource locator". It would be fun to write some code that does this automatically (finds a unique phrase, googles it, confirms there is one hit).

Comment: As a for-instance: if you look at your question above, it strikes me that "on your clipboard (this is solely" is a pretty unlikely string of words. Sure enough, when you type "on your clipboard this is solely" into Google (with the double quotes around it for a "exact match"), you get exactly one hit - this page.